# Admob in Android Studio (help-me)

Tags: android, android-studio, admob

I'm trying to insert the admob app, but gives error in the xml. The following image:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

[Android - AdView missing required XML attribute 'adSize'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20153270/android-adview-missing-required-xml-attribute-adsize)

Also, make sure you reference your Ad-Unit Id as a string.